# SO Chat No Upload Button

Tags: support, chat

I was in an SO chat room with some awesome people and I noticed that  I don't have the upload button, I only have send. All I have is this:

[image]

And that's what another user sees:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

You aren't allowed to upload images in chat until you reach at least 100 reputation, earned with the [create chat rooms](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms) privilege.

> **What other new privileges in chat do I get?**
>
> At 100 reputation you also get access to the "Upload image" button in chat.

Comment: @Ani, this is actually very well hidden. Better mention it also [there](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#talk).

Comment: I am struggling with this while trying to solve a user's problem (the user only has 35 rep). He can't post images in the chat rooms because he doesn't have enough rep :-( http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49023/discussion-between-pycoder-and-fabrizio

Comment: @JakeD  Send via Drive and paste in the url instead